# Select2 Filter Error

Tags: search, filter, yii2

I have a filter gridview like this
[image: IMAGE FILTER GRIDVIEW]

This tag filter is working fine, but whe i go to the page 2, this tag can not be deleted.

VIEW

```
            [
            'attribute' => 'color',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->color->name;
            },
            'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Color::find()->asArray()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
            'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true, 'minimuminputLength' => 3],
            ],
            'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Any Color', 'multiple' => true ],
            'group'=>true,  // enable grouping
            'label' => 'Code',
             'headerOptions' =>
                 ['style'=>'max-width: 70%; font-size: 12px;overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'],
            'contentOptions' =>
                ['style'=>'max-width: 70%; font-size: 12px;overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'],
        ],
        'amount',
```

Comment: Why that tag cannot be deleted? What happens (there is no `x` next to it or there are JS error)?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas, there's x on the tag, but when i change the page into 2 or 3 or nother, and then delete the tag, the tag is get back to the filter, can't be removed.

Comment: I just tested but wasn't able to reproduce the problem. Does your URL change when you try to remove tag (one attribute should be removed from URL)?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas, When i change the page, the url change with there's `page=2` at the end of the url. And when I remove the tag the url doesn't change.